# Instruct RabbitMQ to resend undelivered messages periodically

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, langohr

**Background**

We're using [langohr](http://clojurerabbitmq.info/) to interact with RabbitMQ. We've tried two different approaches to let RabbitMQ resend messages that has not yet been properly handled by our service. One way that works is to send a `basic.nack` with `requeue` set to the `true` but this will resend the message immediately until the service responds with a `basic.ack`. This is a bit problematic if the service for example tries to persist the message to a datastore that is currently down (and is down for a while). It would be better for us to just fetch the undelivered messages say every 20 seconds or so (i.e. we neither do a `basic.ack` or `basic.nack` if the datastore is down, we just let the messages be retained in the queue). We've tried to implement this using an `ExecutorService` whose gist is implemented like this:

```
(let [chan (lch/open conn)]  ; We create a new channel since channels in Langohr are not thread-safe
    (log/info "Triggering \"recover\" for channel" chan)
    (try
      (lb/recover chan)
      (catch Exception e (log/error "Failed to call recover" e))
      (finally (lch/close chan))))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work (the messages are not redelivered and just remains in the queue). If we restart the service the queued messages are consumed correctly. However we have other services that are implemented using [spring-rabbitmq](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/) (in Java) and they seem to be taking care of this out of the box. I've tried looking in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp) to figure out how they do it but I haven't managed to do so yet.

**Question**

How do you instruct RabbitMQ to (re-)deliver messages in the queue periodically (preferably using Langohr)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing with your Spring AMQP apps, but there's nothing built into RabbitMQ for this.

However, it's pretty easy to set up dead-lettering using a TTL to requeue back to the original queue after some period of time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248441/requeueing-dead-letter-messages/31249346#31249346) for examples, links etc.

**EDIT**

However, Spring AMQP **does** have a [retry interceptor which can be configured to suspend the consumer thread for some period(s) during retry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#async-listeners).

Stateful retry rejects and requeues; stateless retry handles the retries internally and has no interaction with the broker during retries.

Comment: Thanks, then we must be mistaken about spring amqp. When we investigated the behavior in one of our production systems and it looked to us that it had this behavior but we're most probably wrong. Big thanks for clarifying this. Do you know if spring-rabbitmq just do nack with requeue or does it do something more fancy?

Comment: basicNack with requeue true/false depending on whether you want an immediate retry or reject/send to DLX/DLQ. Also see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28636231/1173800) which has instructions: we Nack the message, the nack puts the message into a holding queue for N seconds, then it TTLs out of that queue and into another queue that puts it back in the original queue.

It took a little bit of work to setup, but it works great!